# Executing "SHOW PROCESSLIST" using PDO does not return the process list

Tags: mysql, pdo

I am trying to get a list of the MySQL processes programmatically using PHP. But when I run this:

```
$dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=$charset";
$options = [
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
];
try {
     $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $options);
} catch (\PDOException $e) {
     throw new \PDOException($e->getMessage(), (int)$e->getCode());
}

$stmt = $pdo->query('SHOW PROCESSLIST');
while ($row = $stmt->fetch())
{
    print_r($row);
}
```

I get this output:

```
Array
(
    [Id] => 105818
    [User] => myuser
    [Host] => myfqdn.net:59158
    [db] => mydb
    [Command] => Execute
    [Time] => 0
    [State] => starting
    [Info] => SHOW PROCESSLIST
)
```

I have also tried this query:

```
$stmt = $pdo->query('SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PROCESSLIST');
while ($row = $stmt->fetch())
{
    print_r($row);
}
```

With the same results:

```
Array
(
    [ID] => 105906
    [USER] => myuser
    [HOST] => myfqdn.net:59182
    [DB] => mydb
    [COMMAND] => Execute
    [TIME] => 0
    [STATE] => executing
    [INFO] => SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PROCESSLIST
)
```

How do I actually get the real results from those queries, and why is this happening?

Comment: what else do you expect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your user probably doesn't have the PROCESS privilege, so it only has access to its own queries.

You need to run as root or user with grant option:

```
GRANT PROCESS ON *.* TO youruser@'yourhost';
```